# Downloading Sbt Launcher 1.3.10 Failing on CircleCI (Connection Refused, HTTP/HTTPS Issue)

Tags: java, scala, sbt, circleci, typesafe

Starting today, one of our CircleCI Job steps which downloads sbt Launcher 1.3.10 has failed to download. Upon further investigation, the URL that CircleCI has been using no longer accepts connections over http.

The correct URL is https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt-launch/1.3.10/sbt-launch.jar

I am trying to figure out how I can get CircleCI to start downloading from https, as it does not appear to be tied to anything in config.yml. Any suggestions? Our CircleCI setup & host are internal to our organization.

When I download the link using http via FireFox, it pulls the jar from https://akamai.bintray.com , which may be how we have been getting by prior to today. Chrome refuses the connection.

Comment: It looks like the issue lives on repo.typesafe.com refusing the connection. I found the SBT_URL in CircleCI's code and have opened PRs to update to HTTPS. We'll see what comes of it.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague found the root cause:

https://www.lightbend.com/blog/lightbend-to-require-https-on-repos-starting-august-5-2020

CircleCI has yet to update its repo.typesafe.com address for Scala SBT application installation. I have opened PRs to help facilitate that.